# How to upload an audio file to Parse.com - Android

Tags: android, file, audio, parse-platform, upload

I have a path of a file that I want to upload to Parse.com.

For example, one of the file paths is: 
"/storage/emulated/0/app100/2015-06-04_00:45:16_RecordSound.3gp"

Now, I want to upload it to Parse.com. Any solution how to do it?

I've tried to write a method for this, but it's not working:

```
private ParseObject uploadAudioToParse(File audioFile, ParseObject po, String columnName){

    if(audioFile != null){
        Log.d("EB", "audioFile is not NULL: " + audioFile.toString());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(audioFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int read;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
            {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();
        // Create the ParseFile
        ParseFile file = new ParseFile(audioFile.getName() , audioBytes);
        // Upload the file into Parse Cloud
        file.saveInBackground();
        po.put(columnName, file);
    }
    return po;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: is there any output from logcat or is it just not uploading to Parse

Comment: It just not uploading to Parse.

Comment: Answered below, this should be the solution!

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
private ParseObject uploadAudioToParse(File audioFile, ParseObject po, String columnName){

if(audioFile != null){
    Log.d("EB", "audioFile is not NULL: " + audioFile.toString());
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(audioFile));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int read;
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    try {
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
        {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();

    // Create the ParseFile
    ParseFile file = new ParseFile(audioFile.getName() , audioBytes);
    po.put(columnName, file);

    // Upload the file into Parse Cloud
    file.saveInBackground();
    po.saveInBackground();
}
return po;
```

}

Put the object in the ParseObject first, then save the file. Also, I added saving the ParseObject as well (po.saveInBackground()). Since you modified po, you have to save it as well. Maybe you did this outside the method, but your code you linked didn't show this.

Also, maybe try doing this in an AsyncTask and calling save() instead, in order to make sure each step works (if one save or something goes wrong, cancel the task), or use the [SaveCallback](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveInBackground(com.parse.SaveCallback))k provided as follows: ParseObject.saveInBackground( SaveCallback callback); and in the done method call the save to the PO object once the ParseFile successfully saves.

Note: there is a limit to ParseFile size of 10mb, so if the audio file is larger than this, there will be an issue.

Comment: No problem my friend, mark it as the accepted answer so others can see the solution to your question if they have the same issue :)

Comment: I get an error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(byte[])' on a null object reference`